# Renaming files with vidir (moreutils)

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to use vidir from the moreutils package and I have the following issue:
When I load the files I want to rename with vidir like this:

```
$ vidir
```

or like this:

```
$ find -type f | vidir --verbose -
```

vidir displays a number, a tab, and the full path of the files like this:

```
1   ./file1
2   ./file2
3   ./file3
```

or if it isn't the current folder like this:

```
1   ./folder/subfolder1/file1
2   ./folder/subfolder1/file2
3   ./folder/subfolder1/file3
```

Now, I see some advantages in this like the ability to swap file names by swaping the numbers or editing folder names but I just want to rename the files in the same folder and maybe delete some files. My issue is when I use regex to rename the filenames everything could be affected,namely the numbers, the slashes, the dots and the tabs. I tried to remove them at start make my modifications and then rebuild them but vidir complains when I save the file and close the editor.

So how could circumvent this issue? Am I missing something?

EDIT:
I tried again to remove the vidir prefix before I start my modifications and add it back when I'm finished and it seems to be working. These are the functions I used in Vim:

```
" Remove vidir prefix
function! VidirRemovePrefix()
    :%s/\d*\t.\//
endfunction    

" Delete line
function! VidirDeleteLine()
    :s/^\d*\t.*//
endfunction  

" Add vidir prefix back
function! VidirAddPrefix()
    :%s /^/\t.\//
    execute "normal! ggVG"   
    :let i=1 | '<,'>g/^/ s//\=i . ""/ | let i+=1
endfunction
```

For some reason the last function does not always work. If this is the case then I execute the last line (for inserting the numbers) manually in the command line.